# getting the row values with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hello guys? can you please help with this? i have this tables in HTML.what i want to achieve is that, when i click the row the checkbox will be checked and the row will be highlighted.and is it possible with the checkbox column hidden?

```
<table border="1" id="estTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Chris</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Cass</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Aldrin</td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>

</table>
<input type="button" value="Edit" id="editbtn"/>

<div id="out"></div>
```

and i have this javascript to get the values of the selected row.And i was hoping to print one row at a time.

```
 $('#editbtn').click(function(){

    $('#estTable tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').find('td').each(function() {
         $('#out').append("<p>"+$(this).text()+"</p>");
        });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "print one row at a time"?

Comment: when one row is clicked the other row that was clicked will be uncheck. :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets a little easier when you use classes to add more context to your source:

```
<tr>
    <td class="select hidden">
        <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class="name">Chris</td>
    <td class="age">10</td>
</tr>
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('#estTable tbody tr').click(function (e) {
        //when the row is clicked...
        var self = $(this), //cache this
            checkbox = self.find('.select > input[type=checkbox]'), //get the checkbox
            isChecked = checkbox.prop('checked'); //and the current state
        if (!isChecked) {
            //about to be checked so clear all other selections
            $('#estTable .select > input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false).parents('tr').removeClass('selected');
        }
        checkbox.prop('checked', !isChecked).parents('tr').addClass('selected'); //toggle current state
    });
    $('#editbtn').click(function (e) {
        var selectedRow = $('#estTable .select :checked'),
            tr = selectedRow.parents('tr'), //get the parent row
            name = tr.find('.name').text(), //get the name
            age = parseInt(tr.find('.age').text(), 10), //get the age and convert to int
            p = $('<p />'); //create a p element
        $('#out').append(p.clone().text(name + ': ' + age));
    });
});
```

### Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lf9rf/

Answer (score 1):

if i understand the "print one row at a time" correctly, i think you need to empty your "out" selector before executing the new call

```
$('#editbtn').click(function(){

    $('#out').empty();

    $('#estTable tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').find('td').each(function() {
        $('#out').append("<p>"+$(this).text()+"</p>");
    });
});
```

Comment: i meant, when one row is clicked the other row that was checked will be uncheck. :]

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/iyewed/2/edit)*

CSS:

```
.highlight{
    background:gold;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#estTable tr:gt(0)').click(function( e ){ 
  var isChecked = $(this).find(':checkbox').is(':checked');
  if(e.target.tagName !== 'INPUT'){
      $(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', !isChecked);
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: sir? is this possible with the checkbox hidden?